# center text in fpdi?

Tags: php, web, fpdf, fpdi

Is there any way to center text in fpdi so that no matter what length the word has its always centered?

Answer (score 5):

look at http://www.fpdf.de/funktionsreferenz/Cell/ - the parameter $align takes 'C' to center align text.

function:

```
$fpdf->Cell(float w, float h, string txt, mixed border, integer ln, string align, integer fill, mixed link);
```

so:

```
$fpdf->Cell(20,10,"Your Content",0,1,"C");
```

places a cell with width=20, height=10 at your current position and fills it with the given content

Comment: thnx for responding! ... but there is no cell here: $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',12); $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); $pdf->SetXY(80, 400); $pdf->Write(0, "".$person["ED"]);

Comment: well, then you should use Cell instead of write :)

Comment: hmmmm it gives this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getstringwidth` function to work out how wide your text will be.
Divide the answer by 2 (to get the center position), then use that to offset your positioning.

For example :

```
pdf.text 89 - (pdf.getstringwidth("Your text here") / 2),132,"Your text here"
```

will position the text centered on 89mm from the left of the page

Answer (score 1):

This may help you http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/41/

```
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<P ALIGN="center">center a line</P>');
$pdf->MultiCell(75, 8, 'You can<P ALIGN="center">center a line</P>', 'L');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fpdf->Cell($fpdf->w,$fpdf->h,"Your Content",0,1,"C");
```